# Axios get to php file using vuejs cli doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

each time i make a get request to a php file using axios on the vuejs cli, it doesnt run the script, rather it dumps out the full php script without actually running the script.
But if i try accessing that address with the needed parameters from my browser's address bar, it returns the right response.

Here's my code: Vue Component making the get request

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default{
    data(){
        return{
            id : this.$route.params.id,
            post:{}
        }
    },
    created(){
        axios.get('../../php/ajaxfile.php?postid='+this.id).then((response)=>{
            this.post = response.data;
            console.log(response.data);
        }).catch((error) =>{
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

Php Script:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
if(isset($_GET['postid'])){
    $condition  = " id=".$_GET['postid'];
}
$userData = mysqli_query($con,"select * from blogpost WHERE ".$condition );

$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userData)){

    $response[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```

Please help me figure out what i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you are in dev environnement you probably access your vue app by http://localhost:8080.

Your axios should call real url of your local web server :

```
axios.get(process.env.ROOT_API+'/ajaxfile.php?postid='+this.id)
```

And add the ROOT_API definition to your dev and prod config (/config/dev.env.js and /config/prod.env.js) :

here is my dev.env.js :

```
'use strict'
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const prodEnv = require('./prod.env')

module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"',
  ROOT_API: '"http://my-local-domaine.ltd"',
})
```